# Collection Aggregator on Cloudhub

Tags: mule, aggregation, cloudhub

I'm receiving messages over VM queue and aggregating them using collection aggregator. Everything works fine as long as I deploy my application to a single worker. When deployed to more than 1 worker, each worker spins up it's own aggregation and eventually times out because not all messages are accumulated.

This is using mule 3.9.4

```
<spring:beans>
        <spring:bean id="myObjectStore" class="org.mule.util.store.PartitionedInMemoryObjectStore"/>
</spring:beans> 



<collection-aggregator timeout="120000" failOnTimeout="true" storePrefix="wd_data" event-groups-object-store-ref="myObjectStore" doc:name="Collection Aggregator">
            <expression-message-info-mapping messageIdExpression="#[message.id]" correlationIdExpression="#[message.outboundProperties.MULE_CORRELATION_ID]"/>
</collection-aggregator>
```

[see flow-screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XLDmp.png)

Comment: Which version of Mule and which object store configuration are you using?

Comment: Hi @aled - I'm using mule 3.9.4. On cloudhub I've enabled ObjectStore V2 and am initializing the object store by specifying:
<spring:beans>
  <spring:bean id="myDataObjectStore" class="org.mule.util.store.PartitionedInMemoryObjectStore"/>
</spring:beans>

Comment: Please edit your question to add that information. Also, you have to include the aggregator XML snippet to understand how it references the object store.

Comment: @aled - I've added the xml snippets to the description

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that you are creating and using a type of object store that is local to each worker. To use ObjectStore v2 it should use the [predefined object store "_defaultUserObjectStore"](https://docs.mulesoft.com/runtime-manager/managing-application-data-with-object-stores#advanced-information).

Comment: I thought so but there isn't a way to specify the _defaultUserObjectStore to CollectionAggregator. I tried creating an ObjectStore config `<objectstore:config name="ObjectStore__Connector" partition="workday" doc:name="ObjectStore: Connector" objectStore-ref="_defaultUserObjectStore"/>` and use that as a ref to CollectionAggregator, it fails to initialize the application with error.

Comment: `<collection-aggregator timeout="120000" failOnTimeout="true" storePrefix="wdConnector" event-groups-object-store-ref="ObjectStore__Connector" doc:name="Collection Aggregator">
   <expression-message-info-mapping messageIdExpression="#[message.id]" correlationIdExpression="#[message.outboundProperties.MULE_CORRELATION_ID]"/>
  </collection-aggregator>`

Comment: ERROR: org.mule.module.launcher.DeploymentInitException: IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'org.mule.modules.objectstore.generated.adapters.ObjectStoreConnectorConfigBasicAdapter' to required type 'org.mule.api.store.PartitionableObjectStore' for property 'eventGroupsObjectStore': no matching editors or conversion strategy found